# Like query for multiple condition check android

Tags: android, sqlite, where-clause, sql-like

Single query working fine:

```
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM videoplayer where " + KEY_VIDEO_TAG + " like '%"+ searchText +"%'", null);
```

But when I use multiple tag search, then it isn't working:

```
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM videoplayer where " + KEY_TAG_ONE + " like '%"+ searchText +"%'" + KEY_TAG_TWO + " like '%"+ searchText +"%'", null);
```

Please let me know , correct way for this query.

Comment: please let me know the query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are missing some logic operator between those two conditions. eg.:

```
 cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM videoplayer where " + KEY_TAG_ONE + " like '%"+ searchText +"%' OR " + KEY_TAG_TWO + " like '%"+ searchText +"%'", null);
```

Which should select records where KEY_TAG_ONE **or** KEY_TAG_TWO contains searchText